# Trendlines for scatter chart in excel using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
  I am using asp.net datatable to export the data to excel and in that i am using the chart that is inbuilt using com components and i am able to get the chart in excel but my question is how to add trendline in chart. I googled many sites but unable to find the solution. Can any one help me out to find the solution.
```